# Spring dependency injection, to use @Named or @Resource?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

There are two separate annotations to perform dependency injection by name in Spring, `javax.annotation.Resource` and `javax.inject.Named`.  The [documentation at Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) indicates `@Resource` should be used for injection by name:

> If you intend to express annotation-driven injection by name, do not
>   primarily use @Autowired, even if is technically capable of referring
>   to a bean name through @Qualifier values. Instead, use the JSR-250
>   @Resource annotation, which is semantically defined to identify a
>   specific target component by its unique name, with the declared type
>   being irrelevant for the matching process.

The above is a bit confusing, as Spring is only advocating `@Resource` instead of `@Autowired` combined with `@Qualifer`. There is no mention of `@Named` until [later in the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-standard-annotations).

JSR-250 defines `@Resource`, whereas JSR-330 defines `@Inject` and `@Named`.  I know they can be mixed-and-matched within Spring fairly easily.  Which JSR to use?

It seems like portability with Guice and CDI would be nice, and hence to use the JSR-330 annotations.  On the other hand, the documentation also points out at a couple of [limitations](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-standard-annotations-limitations) within Spring when using JSR-330 annotations.

What is the best practice (if there is one) for annotation injection-by-name?

Thank you.

Comment: The limitations mentioned just refer to how Spring will use those annotations, and how the annotations that Spring introduces are much more robust for working with Spring specifically.

Comment: The limitations do not seem all that onerous. Though they do exist.  It seems a lot of this would be simpler if Spring had also adopted the additional CDI annotations.

Answer (score 1):

@Resource is older and is supported since Spring 2.5 while @Named support has been added in Spring 3.0 and both of them can be used to achieve the same purpose of injection-by-name.

When using Spring, my concerns for preferring one over the other would be backward compatibility with Spring 2.5 and whether javax.inject can be added/assumed-to-be on the classpath or not.

Comment: @Inject @Named("beanName") doesn't work for me in spring 3.0.7 but @Resource(name="beanName") do.

Comment: Is javax.inject or javaee-api jar on the classpath? Just make sure it is because support for \@Inject and \@Named has been added since Spring 3.0.0.